# Linear systems of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, motivation

I would like to see an example of a real physical situation where one can find a set of variables evolving according to a system of linear differential equations.

I wasn't able to find any such example so I'm asking here.

Comment: Examples abound. The fundamental phenomena in nature such as described by Newtonian mechanics and its relativistic generalization, electromagnetism, and quantum mechanics all have dynamic motion described by linear differential equations (general relativity is a notable exception having non-linear dynamics).

Comment: See Newton's second law, Hamilton's equations, the Euler-Lagrange equations, Hamilton-Jacobi equations, Maxwell's equations, Schroedinger's equation, the Dirac equation, the Poisson equation, &c.

Answer (score 2):

When you have a point mass $m$ that can move in the (horizontal) $y$-direction, but is drawn to the origin by a spring then it moves according to the ODE
$$m\>\ddot y=-f\> y\ ,$$
where $f>0$ denotes the spring constant. Assume now that you have two such masses with origins at a certain distance of each other. Then they independently move according to the system of ODEs
$$m_1\>\ddot y_1=-f_1\> y_1\ ,\qquad m_2\>\ddot y_2=-f_2\> y_2\ .\tag{1}$$
To make things more interesting we now connect the two masses by a very weak "coupling" spring, whereby we assume that the system is in equilibrium when $y_1=y_2=0$. The ODE system $(1)$ then has to be replaced by
$$m_1\>\ddot y_1=-f_1\> y_1+\kappa(y_2-y_1)\ ,\qquad m_2\>\ddot y_2=-f_2\> y_2-\kappa(y_2-y_1)\ ,\tag{2}$$
where $\kappa>0$ encodes the constant of the "coupling" spring. Introducing velocities one then can convert $(2)$ into the system
$$\left.\eqalign{\dot y_1&=v_1 \cr
\dot v_1&=-(f_1+\kappa)y_1+\kappa y_2 \cr \dot y_2&= v_2 \cr
\dot v_2&=\kappa y_1-(f_2+\kappa)y_2\cr}\right\}\ .$$
The latter is a system of the form envisaged in the question.

Comment: I did this experiment (and taught this also) where we had the 8 springs and how do we configure the springs to get degenerate modes. Throughly interesting and it links back to the lattice model with phonon propagations and Hamilton mechanics :).

Comment: Piggy banking on Christian Blatter's answer, a common example that I have seen in textbooks usually is the mixing tanks problem.  Where talks containing different concentrations of salt or other precipitate empty into one another.